# How do I retrieve firebase data in web

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

So, All I need to do is to count the total user data.

I tried this code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: "",
    clientEmail: "",
    privateKey: ""
  }),  
  databaseURL: ""
});

var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref();

ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
});
```

This code works in `firebase-admin` which I am using NodeJS, but I when I want to retrieve total data in the normal `javascript`. It doesn't work.

No, I dont try this NodeJS code in the web. I tried the javascript one. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but firebase-admin is supposed to be used from a backend admin environment. It is not safe to use it from a client browser as you have administrative privileges.

Comment: I know, what I'm trying to ask is the same kind of method but with in javascript.